# Single logout button for facebook and google

Tags: java, android-studio

I am working on a android  project which got both google and facebook login option. I am stucked on logout button.

I want to have a logout button which works for both the account. I mean if users are logged in through google then logout button should logout users from google and if user are login through facebook then the same button should logout from facebook

Comment: Hint: and what is your specific question? For sure, it is not "so, here you got my requirements, now tell me how to solve my problem?"

Comment: The button listener executes some code. The code has to check the status (checked into Google or checked into Facebook) and respond accordingly. Post an [MCVE] with specific questions / problems

Answer (score -1):

You could store a variable, "facebook" or "google" based on the type of sign-in and use that variable to sign-out the user from that one single button.